# Dynamically changing the height of the cell and UIImage based on the ratio of actual image

Tags: ios, afnetworking

This is what I have tried so far

I defined a global variable

```
float imgHeight;
```

Then in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I do this

```
        size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(scribbleImage.image.CGImage);
        size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(scribbleImage.image.CGImage);
        CGFloat ratio = 312/pixelsWide;
        pixelsHigh = pixelsHigh*ratio;
```

Then in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
return pixlesHeight;
```

Now since `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I always get `pixelsHeight as 0`.

I cannot figure out another way of doing this. Should I redefine a UIImage in heightForRow and do this

```
[scribbleImage setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:scribble[@"scribble_image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
```

in there as well?! There should be an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Does your table only have one image at a time? Is it in every row?

Comment: it's very row. every row has just one image in the cell

Comment: The same image, or different ones?

Comment: Let me be more clear. Does every row have the same image? Does this image change over time?

Comment: @rdelmar nope it changes. it changes with my JSON data

Comment: That doesn't answer my first question. At a particular point in time is there more than one image in the table, or does every row have the same image?

Comment: @rdelmar no there are more than one images in the table and yes they change. every cell has a different image in it, that is why I want to resize the image vertically (like Facebook and Tumblr) so that it looks better

Comment: You should just do it all in heightForRowAtIndexPath. Are you having some trouble doing it there? Just calculate the height for the image at that index path, and return it.  Also, why are you using setImageWithURL, which is an IKImageView method (or is that your own method)?

Comment: @rdelmar setImageWithURL is also an AF Networking method. thats the Library I am using for asynchronous networking library. Also yes I am having troubles trying to calculate the hight dynamically. Thats what I have specified in my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26070/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-jonathan)

Answer (score 0):

Do that in heightForRowAtIndexPath. As I understand your concerns about wasting processing and loading time, just store the UIImage within your array of items once processed in order to use that same one in cellForRowAtIndexPath, avoiding to create a new one then.